# How to make a perfect circlular pattern for bullet hell in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm messing around making a bullet hell game using pygame. I'm trying to make a circular spread pattern. The following piece of code has had me stuck. Below is the class of my bullet with an update function that updates the bullets position

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, angle):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, "bullet.png")).convert()
    self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2 , HEIGHT / 2)
    self.angle = angle
    self.counter = 0
    self.speedx = 5
    self.speedy = 5

def update(self):

    self.rect.x += self.speedx * math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) 
    self.rect.y += self.speedy * math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))
    if(self.rect.right > 640 or self.rect.left < 0 or self.rect.bottom > 480 or self.rect.top < 0):
        self.kill()
```

The patterns group function was created as

```
for x in range(12):
    bullet_sprite1.add(Bullet(angle))
    angle += 30
```

While the pattern is generated it does not create a perfect circle as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1qRY.png)

How can I go about making it a perfect circular spread

Comment: I don't know pygame, but it looks like your circle is being clipped on the top & left. So reduce its radius &/or move its centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because `pygame.Rect`s can't have floats as their x and y coordinates and pygame just truncates the floats that you assign to the rect. You can add two more attributes `self.posx` and `self.posy` to store and update the actual position and then assign them to `self.rect.center`.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, angle):
        # Rest of the attributes omitted.
        self.speedx = 5 * math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) 
        self.speedy = 5 * math.sin(math.radians(self.angle))
        self.posx = self.rect.centerx
        self.posy = self.rect.centery

    def update(self):
        self.posx += self.speedx
        self.posy += self.speedy
        self.rect.center = (self.posx, self.posy)
        if (self.rect.right > 640 or self.rect.left < 0
                or self.rect.bottom > 480 or self.rect.top < 0):
            self.kill()
```

---

You could also use vectors.

```
from pygame.math import Vector2

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, angle):
        # Rest of the attributes omitted.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(WIDTH / 2 , HEIGHT / 2))
        self.velocity = Vector2(1, 0).rotate(angle) * 5
        self.pos = Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.velocity
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```